# og:image ignored

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, fbconnect

I have problem. When I share my website on fb, it doesn't display image. My code:

```
  <meta property="og:title" content="Zapust.pl - życie granic wschodnich"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://zapust.pl"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://zapust.pl/assets/temp.png"/>
```

I have no app_id. JS code:

```
    <script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=zapust.pl" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/share-fb-icon.gif"></a>
```

Comment: Use linter: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fzapust.pl Seems that your image is to small, it must be at least 200px for both height and width

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your comment should be an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, use [linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

According to it, your image was to small, it must be at least 200px for both height and width.